# Getting Error While Creating JAR from the SPARK SCALA MAVEN Project in Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, scala, maven, apache-spark

I have Created a maven Project for Spark Scala and written some piece of code. I have to bind it as a JAR file and run it from the Edge Node(shell environment). But i am facing below Error. Please advise

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.11:compile (default) on project XYZ: Execution default of goal org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.11:compile failed: Plugin org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:2.11 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to collect dependencies at org.scala-tools:maven-scala-plugin:jar:2.11 -> org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:jar:2.0.4: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.reporting:maven-reporting-impl:pom:2.0.4 from/to maven-cto-dev (https://www.artifactrepository.xyz.net/artifactory/maven-cto-dev): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

Provide Certificate Path on eclipse.ini file in C drive